# No puedo hacer pantalla completa en algunos telefonos Huawei

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services

Lo que intento hacer es mostrar mi app en pantalla completa. Se supone que el siguiente código hace eso si lo agrego al onCreate de mi activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

if( bar!=null )
  {
  bar.hide();
  }

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Mi código funciona en teléfonos Mate Xs, MediaPad M6, MatePad Pro, emuladores, algunos Samsung y LG.

pero no funciona en Huawei P40, P40 Pro, Mate 30 Pro, Mate 30, Nova 5T, P30.

Replicar mi problema es muy facil

1 Abrir Android Studio

2 Crear un nuevo proyecto

3 Seleccionar 'Empty Activity'

4 Agregar este código

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

  ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

  if( bar!=null )
    {
    bar.hide();
    }

  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
```

5 Compilar y correr el proyecto en alguno de los telefonos Huawei donde no funciona y verán una barra negra arriba de la pantalla

Cómo hago para que no salga esa barra?

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar esta información : https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema tiene que ver con el ["display cutout"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout)

Prueba agregando la siguiente configuración en tu manifest

```
<activity android:name=".FullScreenActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

luego agrega este código en tu activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    HideSystemUI();
}
 
private void HideSystemUI() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
        getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
    }
}
```